# Converting an Object to an Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script which retrieves data from the Magento API If I run the following code:

```
$category_tree = $client->catalogCategoryTree($session_id);
print_r($category_tree);
```

The output is as follows:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [category_id] => 1
    [parent_id] => 0
    [name] => Root Catalog
    [position] => 0
    [level] => 0
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [name] => Root Category
                    [is_active] => 1
                    [position] => 1
                    [level] => 1
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 8
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => Designer
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [position] => 1
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 12
                                                    [parent_id] => 8
                                                    [name] => Chanel
                                                    [is_active] => 1
                                                    [position] => 1
                                                    [level] => 3
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 13
                                                    [parent_id] => 8
                                                    [name] => Chanel
                                                    [is_active] => 1
                                                    [position] => 2
                                                    [level] => 3
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 14
                                                    [parent_id] => 8
                                                    [name] => Chanel
                                                    [is_active] => 1
                                                    [position] => 3
                                                    [level] => 3
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 15
                                                    [parent_id] => 8
                                                    [name] => Chanel
                                                    [is_active] => 1
                                                    [position] => 4
                                                    [level] => 3
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [4] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 16
                                                    [parent_id] => 8
                                                    [name] => Chanel
                                                    [is_active] => 1
                                                    [position] => 5
                                                    [level] => 3
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 7
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => Shop Bags
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [position] => 2
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 5
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => DifferentCategory
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [position] => 3
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [category_id] => 6
                                                    [parent_id] => 5
                                                    [name] => 1
                                                    [is_active] => 1
                                                    [position] => 1
                                                    [level] => 3
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [category_id] => 4
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                    [name] => Sample Category
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [position] => 6
                                    [level] => 2
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

When attempting to convert this to an array whilst storing the `name` values, I receive the following errors upon executing the `print_r()` function:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\create_products.php on line 151
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\create_products.php on line 151
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\create_products.php on line 151
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\create_products.php on line 151
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\create_products.php on line 151
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\create_products.php on line 151
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => )
```

My code is below:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($category_tree as $designer_category) {
    $result[] = $designer_category->name;
}
print_r($result);
```

I need to be able to store the values for `name` as an array. I've tried typecasting `$category_tree` to an array with no luck.

Could anybody please shed some light on where I'm going wrong here? Thank you very much in advance for any insight that you can offer.

Comment: I'm not sure what behaviour you want, but at the moment all you are doing is looping through the properties of the top level object.

Comment: There's only a single category at the top-level of the tree, so it doesn't make sense to loop over it. Just use `$category_tree->name`. If you want to get all the names, you need to process the object recursively, looping over $category_tree->children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work, because you have object, not array.
You must go deeper and deeper through all childrens.

Try use recursion, it isn't ideal example, but shows idea:

```
function goDeeper($object, &$results) {
    if (!empty($object->name)) {
        $results[] = $object->name;
    }

    if (!empty($object->children)) {
        foreach ($object->children as $child) {
            goDeeper($child, $results);
        }
    }
}

$results = [];
$category_tree = $client->catalogCategoryTree($session_id);
goDeeper($category_tree, $results);

print_r($results);
```